# ESLint errors on JSX/React

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am working with React and this is my first time, I need to know what this errors are and how to fix it

```
app/app.js
  21:49   error  'socket' is missing in props validation for App  react/prop-types
  22:47   error  'room' is missing in props validation for App    react/prop-types
  23:47   error  'mode' is missing in props validation for App    react/prop-types
  24:47   error  'user' is missing in props validation for App    react/prop-types
  26:32   error  'socket' is missing in props validation for App  react/prop-types
  26:57   error  'room' is missing in props validation for App    react/prop-types
  26:80   error  'mode' is missing in props validation for App    react/prop-types
  26:103  error  'user' is missing in props validation for App    react/prop-types
```

and here is the file where I am getting the error

```
const query = qs.parse(location.search);
const config = {
  socket : query.socket || 'http://10.28.10.85:1101/chat',
  room   : query.room || 'BJTest',
  mode   : query.mode || 'player',
  user   : query.user || 'Alberto',
};

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return (<div>
      <div><strong>Socket:</strong> {this.props.socket}</div>
      <div><strong>Room:</strong> {this.props.room}</div>
      <div><strong>Mode:</strong> {this.props.mode}</div>
      <div><strong>User:</strong> {this.props.user}</div>
      <hr />
      <Chat socket={this.props.socket} room={this.props.room} mode={this.props.mode} user={this.props.user} />
    </div>);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to define proptypes that are used in `App` and `Chat` components. See: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es6-classes for definition.

Example:

```
App.propTypes = {
  socket: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  room: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  mode: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  user: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```